# processing drag-n-drop with nested HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm using HTML5 drag and drop, and I have drop targets which can be either an empty `<div>` or a a `<div>` with an `<img>` as a child node.

To make the divs drop targets I'm setting `onDrop=` on those divs.

If I end a drop on a div containing an image, `e.target` is the image node.

If I end the drop on an empty div, `e.target` is the div.

To process the drop I need to find the id of the div, and since `e.target` can be either the image or the div, I'm checking `e.target.parentNode` in case I don't find the information I'm looking for in `e.target`.

Is there a way I can set things up so that `e.target` will always be the div? Or is looking up the parentNode chain standard operating procedure?

Comment: `e.target.parentNode` is okay!

Comment: if you set the event listener on the the div then `this` is the div, by the way don't put event listeners in the HTML, put them in the javascript

Comment: @Saar - ok I'll try that. I'm using react, so I'm setting the listeners in the HTML - unless there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

It is old question, but the answer might help someone. Use DIV element like below:

```
<div id="my-div" onDrop="dropped('my-div');">
    ...
</div>
```

You will always get id 'my-div' in `dropped` even if drop happened on child on any level.